# Excel export of DataTables not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, excel, datatables, mobile-safari

I'm trying to implement the "Export to Excel" functionality on a JQuery DataTable on my web page. The initialization of the datatable is done as follows:

```
$('#myData').dataTable( {
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
         {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'Export to Excel',
        title: 'myData'
    }]
 });
```

The above code works fine on Google Chrome on my desktop as well as android phones, however on a Safari browser on my iPhone/iPad it does not work and the button would not even show up. I read on the DataTables documentation that the excelHtml5 is not supported on Safari, however the 'excel' button type says is supported on all modern browsers. So if anybody has been able to solve achieve this functionality and got this working on an iPhone please let me know the solution to this issue. TIA!

Comment: I'm getting a very similar issue. Only difference is that the button shows up in Safari both desktop and mobile, and it sometimes but not always works on Safari desktop. On Safari mobile, clicking it doesn't do anything. Has this issue been reported in the DataTables forums? P.S. I'm using an older version of DataTables.